# How to show custom message when somebody clicks on refresh button of Coldfusion cfGrid (When session is out)?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using Coldfusion (9.0.1) cfGrid to populate some data. Code is given below

```
   <cfform id="ViewNewCustomerReport" name="ViewNewCustomerReport">
    <div class="buttonClass">
        <cfinput type="button" id="generateReport" name="generateReport" 
        value="Generate Report" />

        <cfinput type="hidden" name="filters" id="filters" 
        bind="javascript:GenerateReport({generateReport@click})"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="gridContainer">
    <cfgrid name="NewCustomerReport" autoWidth="Yes" colheaderbold="true"  selectonload="false" width="710"
    bind="url:index.cfm?fuseaction=ReportsCommon.GetNewCustomerReport&page={cfgridpage}&pagesize={cfgridpagesize}&gridsortcolumn={cfgridsortcolumn}&gridsortDirection={cfgridsortdirection}&filter={filters}"
    bindOnLoad="false" striperows="true" striperowcolor="##F6F6F6" format="html" pagesize="10">
        <cfgridcolumn name="COMPANY_NAME" width="280" header="Company Name" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="SUBJECT_ASSIGNED" width="280" header="Subject Assigned" />
        <cfgridcolumn name="NO_OF_USERS" header="No. Of users" width="180" /> 
    </cfgrid>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapperDiv"><label id="lblError" class="CustomError"></label></div>
</cfform>
```

And this is the javascript part

```
var GenerateReport = function(filters){
    var returnVal;
    var checkForm = $('#ViewNewCustomerReport').validationEngine('validate');
    returnVal = dateFrom + '|' + dateTo;
    if(checkForm)
    {
        var gridObject = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject("NewCustomerReport");
        var store = gridObject.getStore();
        store.addListener("load",function(){
            if(store.data.items == 0)
            {
                gridObject.setVisible(false);
                $("#gridContainer").hide();
                $("#wrapperDiv").show();
                $("#wrapperDiv").css("text-align","center");
                $("#lblError").text("No record found").css({"font-size":"20px","font-weight":"normal"});
            }   
            else
            {
                gridObject.setVisible(true);
                $("#gridContainer").show();
                $("#wrapperDiv").hide();    
            }
        });             
    }
    else
    {
        $('#gridContainer').hide();         
    }
    return  returnVal;  
};
```

Now if somebody logout the application in another tab and then refreshes the Grid it show some message like

***CFGRID: TOTALROWCOUNT missing from response data [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information]***

When Session is out in return the Json data collected is like that 
***{"isSessionOut":true} HTTP Status code 200 HTTP status Message OK***

So my Question is instead of showing that default error message i want to show my custom message like **session is out please log in to continue**.

how can these be achieved ?? Thanks in advance ......

Answer (score 2):

Every bind operation/Ajax call in coldfusion has an OnError/BindError handler function, which can be called at the time of some error, or we can call it with the help of HTTP response by setting the HTTP status code.

Whenever you want some 
self generated error message, you can write this code at response/Action page of your site:

`error = getpagecontext().getresponse().setstatus(306, "Your session is out");`

(you can set HTTP status code any thing more then 300 but i have checked only for 306 and it works)

by this you can call onError function of your CFGRID

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jQuery or similar plugin that runs in the outer page and detects inactivity, then it can even count down when session is timing out and gracefully take your user back to a login page. This way you wont have this issue on any page.

This one is good, there are many others also
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHEF9/4/)

Comment: I Have already showing a Custom popup messageEveryWhere when session is out. But my Question is here that in CFGrid how can we detect/catch the response data and show the message a/c to that.CFGrid bind attribute is used to bind the data in the grid.

Comment: My suggestion is that you address this at an application level so that individual components don't time out, that the entire page does and then you wont have this issue.

Comment: Sorry Dale i have not understand the last line you commented.Can you please elaborate it a little ..

Comment: Adding that type of solution to your pages will mean that at the timeout, lets say its 30minutes, the user will get a warning and either be logged out or choose to continue. Thus the data in the datagrid will never fail due to session timeouts.